# Which collection assertion strategy is used with TestCaseSource collection return values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assertions, nunit-3.0

Using nUnit 3.4.1.

When using `TestCaseSource` to new up a list of `TestCaseData` items:

```
new TestCaseData(new [] {"value1", "value2"}).Returns(new [] {"value2", "value1"})
```

in my unit test, when returning an array that looks like the input data:

```
new [] {"value1", "value2"}
```

for the `Returns` value shown above, I get a failed test, because I'm assuming nUnit is using `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`, which implies the same order.

Tried using an extra parameter in the `TestCaseData` initialization and a `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` instead, and it worked

Can I customize that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is not configurable. The fluent `Returns` method is treated the same as `ExpectedResult`. NUnit only checks for equality. The [NUnit code that handles this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Commands/TestMethodCommand.cs) is fairly straight forward,

```
if (testMethod.HasExpectedResult)
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(testMethod.ExpectedResult, result);
```

The workaround to pass in the expected value as a second parameter and use the `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` is the correct one. NUnit will not be changing the semantics of `ExpectedResult` to allow you to use arbitrary asserts. You are likely seeing `AreEqual` and `AreEquivalent` as very close in semantic meaning, but they are very different internally.

Comment: That's what I did pretty much. Would be nice to be able to configure this behaviour. Thanks! I understand they are very different but a simple defaulted to equality enum to customize would suffice to be able to change the one being used.

Comment: Feel free to enter an issue. My initial feeling is that we won't support it, but if enough of our users support it, we will consider it.